# I want to remove quotes from my string in curl

Tags: string, curl

I am getting a token from a website using curl. I got the token almost clean but i cant get the quotes away from my string.
This is my code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
$card = curl_exec($ch);
$token4 = getStr($card, 'key: ',',affid','');
```

The result of the string is 'c35372273095b4c5a23939a137317930'

But i want to get the token without the quotes.

Comment: `trim($strt, "'");` will remove all `'` at beginning and at the end

Comment: How are you determining if the quotes are in the string or not?  What is the length of this string?

Comment: $token4 = getStr($card, 'key: ',',affid','');

trim($token4, "'");
echo $token4;
Do i need to do it like this? because it doesnt work. Thanks for helping btw

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php) to remove characters at the beginning and at the end.

Your code should look like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
$card = curl_exec($ch);
$token4 = getStr($card, 'key: ',',affid','');
$token4 = trim($token4, "'"); // removes '
$token4 = trim($token4); // removes all white spaces 
// echo $token4;
```

Comment: Thanks, the first is gone but only at the end it's still there. You know why that is?

Comment: @PeterCadel is there maybe a whitespace?

Comment: I dont know what it is, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for helping :), i dont know why, but the last one doesn't go away :(. Its very strange.